# Theme not working when using non-standard port number

Tags: theming

I've been having some performance issues with my local **WAMP** install and saw a suggestion to move Apache to a different port.  I achieved this by updating `httpd.conf`:

```
Listen 89
ServerName localhost:89
```

I also update my **vhosts** to use the new port:

```
<VirtualHost *:89> 
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\mysite" 
</VirtualHost>
```

This works.  I can now access the site via `mysite.local:89`.  However, the site appears unstyled because the CSS and JS files are not linked properly. For example, the following CSS file cannot be found:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.local/sites/default/files/css/css_0-h4tIT-Kdty3gonMCX41fM-7MgTrV9BMd5XQoTqeaQ.css" media="all">
```

I need the CSS and JS to use `mysite.local:89` instead of `mysite.local`.  When I change this manually via the web inspector it works.

How can I change the CSS and JS imports to use the new port?

**Update on WAMP Slowness**

For anyone who is interested, WAMP is running much better now. I followed the recommendations in the following article (specifically, I disabled IPv6, put all host file entries on one line, moved Apache to a new port): http://devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should just be a matter of setting the `$base_url` in [settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!default!default.settings.php/7)

> If Drupal is generating incorrect URLs on your site, which could be in HTML headers (links to CSS and JS files) or visible links on pages (such as in menus), uncomment the Base URL statement below (remove the leading hash sign) and fill in the absolute URL to your Drupal installation.

For your case that would be:

```
$base_url = 'http://mysite.local:89';
```

Comment: So simple! I was definitely overthinking this one. Thanks!

Comment: And for anyone who is interested, WAMP is running much better now.  I followed the recommendations in this article (disabled IPv6 etc): https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow